# Seed graphite checks to cabot database

Tags: monitoring, graphite, alerts, collectd

I have the list of metrics those will be coming from graphite.
I want to seed checks for these graphite metrics in the Cabot database.

So when I open the graphite UI first time, I should see my seeded graphite checks.

For this which database tables I need to change?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but do you need to copy stored data from whisper database used by graphite to another tool?

Comment: Yes.
Cabot is the tool which reads the graphite metrics and displays in its UI.
Using this metrics we can configure alerts in the cabot.
Cabot stores all this alerts information in its database.
Now I want to seed this information to Cabot database without making use of Cabot UI.

Comment: Whisper is the database behind graphite. You can use this script to recursively read whisper files and send them to another server in graphite format: https://github.com/axibase/atsd-graphite-finder/blob/master/bin/migrate.py. You can modify this line `socket.sendall("%s %s %s\n" % (metric, val, timestamp))` to send data in a different format or dump data to file.